# Google Map V2 shows blank screen when downloaded from google play store

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I made a simple maps project, it works great when installing it form the eclipse onto my tablet, however, when I uploaded it to the google play store, it turns out that when you download it from the store, the map is blank, I tried and realized it's true

this is how the app looks like when installing it form my eclipse to my device

[image: app on my eclipse]

and this is how it looks like when I downloaded it back to my device from the google play store.

[image]

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zivkesten.find_a_place"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.zivkesten.find_a_place.view.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/WhatsOround"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   >
</application>

</manifest>
```

why is this happening? I updated everything in Eclipse to the latest possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the SHA-1 fingerprint from the key you signed the app with? When in debug mode, it uses a different key than the one you publish with, so both will need to be authorized on the API console for it to work. I had the same issue and this solved it for me.

Comment: when exporting i have a SHA1 key and an MD5 key, which one are you reffrering to? this is the first time i am uploading an app on to the store so i have never seen this MD5 key before

Comment: i used the new SHA1 key and it worked thank you! but can you tell me what is the MD5 key?